# limit in _source in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

This is my source from ES:

```
 "_source": {
                "queryHash": "query412236215",
                "id": "query412236215",
                "content": {
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "name": "Catalog",
                            "type": "varchar(10)",
                            "typeSignature": {
                                "rawType": "varchar",
                                "typeArguments": [],
                                "literalArguments": [],
                                "arguments": [
                                    {
                                        "kind": "LONG_LITERAL",
                                        "value": 10
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "data": [
                        [
                            "apm"
                        ],
                        [
                            "postgresql"
                        ],
                        [
                            "rest"
                        ],
                        [
                            "system"
                        ],
                        [
                            "tpch"
                        ]
                    ],
                    "query_string": "show catalogs",
                    "execution_time": 1979
                },
                "createdOn": "1514269074289"
            }
```

How can i get the n records inside _source.data?
Lets say _source.data have 100 records , I want only 10 at a time ,also is it possible to assign offset for next 10 records?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html). As far as I know there isn't any built-in solution because Elasticsearch is primarily built for searching and filtering with a document store only as a secondary concern.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I am also using ES for searching only not for storage. I checked scripting but it doesn't look to solve my problem, But inner hits can solve but that too with just one layer of json,my json has more then one. Please post if you have solution related to inner hits.

Comment: I believe you but what I'm saying is that the capabilities that you expect, to paginate `_source.data` in a recursive manner, is more associated with a document store than a search engine like Elasticsearch :)

Answer (score 0):

First, the [order in `_source` is stable](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html), so it's not totally impossible:

> When you get a document back from Elasticsearch, any arrays will be in
>   the same order as when you indexed the document. The _source field
>   that you get back contains exactly the same JSON document that you
>   indexed.
>
> However, arrays are indexed—made searchable—as multivalue fields,
>   which are unordered. At search time, you can’t refer to "the first
>   element" or "the last element." Rather, think of an array as a bag of
>   values.

However, [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) doesn't cover this, so you're out of luck with arrays.

Also inner hits won't help you. [They do have options for `sort`, `size`, and `from`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#_options), but those will only return the matched subdocuments and I assume you want to page freely through all of them.

So your final hope is scripting, where you can build whatever you want. But this is probably not what you want:

1. Do you really need paging here? Results are transferred in a compressed fashion, so the overhead of paging is probably much larger than transferring the data in one go.
2. If you do need paging, because your array is huge, you probably want to restructure your documents.